# change css of one DIV when scrolled over another

Tags: javascript, css, function, scroll, offset

I'm trying to get this to work with no avail. I am trying to get a menu item's CSS to change when I am scrolling past a specific DIV.

In this case, I am trying to get a menu item (#menu-item-3907) to change it's background color when I am scrolling over the div labelled #section-1.

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
var t = $("#section-1").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
{   
    $('#menu-item-3907').css({"display":"none"});
}
});
```

Comment: I don't think `scroll()` does what you think it does. Perhaps you want `on('hover'...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = $("#section-1").scrollTop();

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > t){
        $('#menu-item-3907').css({"background":"yellow"});
    }
});
```

Tried using HTML:

```
<div id="section-1">Section 1</div>
<div id="menu-item-3907" style="margin-top:1500px">Menu</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. The problem is that the background changes immediately rather than when it's scrolling over the correct div.
Live example: http://dev.themarketcreative.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    <script>
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;



    if(scroll_pos>=300) {
       $("#menu-item-3907").css("background-color","#B44DFE");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#menu-item-3907").css("background-color","#FFF");
    }
}); 

    </script>
<div id="#section-1" style="color:pink;height:300px;border:1px solid">
hi

  </div>  

<div id="menu-item-3907"  style="color:blue;height:300px;border:1px solid">

hi
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LnWhJ/1/

Comment: This is working great mate. Any way of reverting the background change when you scroll past it?

Comment: Actually, looking at it, it's not working as I need. Maybe it's a coding error on my side but the link just turns purple if you scroll down slightly even if you aren't on the page where the #section-1 is.

Comment: No apologies necessary!
It still seems to be doing the same, not sure why: http://dev.themarketcreative.com/

Comment: i'hv checked http://dev.themarketcreative.com/....there color of home in top menu is changing ..nothing else ....you can set height of your div..as i set 300

Comment: Hey, to be a bit clearer, the Home link in the menu is the one I'm looking for it to change colour when hovering over the div, which it is but it's not cancelling once I've scrolled past the div.

I tried setting the div to 300px with no luck.